# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException in android

Tags: java, android, json

I have one url, I want to take these data and show it into list view using JSON, but when I run it, there's something error, that said :

> JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

This is my code:

```
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray ();

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray innerJsonArray = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
            JSONObject c = innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            // Storing each json item in variable
            map.put("atasan", c.get("atasan").toString());
            map.put("kode_agen", c.get("kode_agen").toString());
            map.put("jenis", c.get("jenis").toString());
            map.put("no_aaji", c.get("no_aaji").toString());
            map.put("nama_agen", c.get("nama_agen").toString());

            AgenList.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            MainActivity.this, AgenList, R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] {ATASAN, KODE_AGEN, JENIS, NO_AAJI, NAMA_AGEN}, new int [] {R.id.atasan, R.id.kode_agen, R.id.jenis, R.id.no_aaji, R.id.nama_agen});

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

I don't know where's my fault, I hope somebody can help me to solve this problem ?

this is the example data that i want to take :
{"atasan":"THOMAS SUNARDI ",
"kode_agen":"024932",
"jenis":"Regional","no_aaji":"11529943* "
,"nama_agen":"YONATHAN ADRIYANTO WIDJAJA"}

Comment: Is it possible to paste your JSON?

Comment: you have to get the data using array not object ..

Comment: Aoyama Nanami Is it working for you!!!

Comment: @Aoyama Nanami if my answer help you then accept the answer!!

Comment: @janmejoy your answer can't help me, it doesn't work

Comment: @AoyamaNanami what you are really getting same error!!

Comment: @AoyamaNanami try this link for json parsing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

Answer (score 2):

so do this..

```
JSONObject jsonObj= new JSONObject(new String(buffer));

JSONArray data = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

 for(int i =0; i < data .length(); i++){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen the JSON yet but I presume that the error must be on this line

```
JSONObject c = innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
```

try this:

```
JSONArray c = innerJsonArray.getJSONArray(0);
```

Comment: JSON from web service as like this :

[{"atasan":"THOMAS SUNARDI ",
"kode_agen":"024932",
"jenis":"Regional",
"no_aaji":"11529943* ",
"nama_agen":"YONATHAN ADRIYANTO WIDJAJA"},
{....
......
......
......}]